# CasperJS script does not find correct button and onclick-event

Tags: javascript, button, css-selectors, casperjs

my casperjs script plays a video, then the webpage present 2 buttons either to continue viewing or to click "fill". The "fill option is what I am after but the buttons have same id, except for the desired option has an acivate-access() function:

```
button id="activate" class="btn btn lg" onclick="activate_access();
```

I tried doing this.click('#activate') and this.click('#activate.btn.btn-lg') but that just reloads a new video so I figure casper.evaluate or other approach is needed and how do I pass the correct onclick event(which is acivate_access();) to casperjs?
Code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
            logLevel: "warning",
            verbose: true,
            onPageInitialized: function() {
                                            console.log("page opened");
                                            },

});
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36  (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36');
casper.viewport = {width:1200, height:800}; 
casper.start(url, function() {

    casper.wait(1000, function() {                             

                    casper.capture('look.png');
                    console.log('did screenshot');

    });


});

casper.wait(4000, function() {
console.log('clicking play');
this.click('#video');
casper.wait(37000);
casper.capture('play.png');

pres_url=this.getCurrentUrl();    

console.log(pres_url);
});

casper.evaluate(function() {
document.getElementById('activate').click();

});

casper.wait(500);
casper.run();
```

Comment: If different elements have the same `id` attribute, then you really should get angry at the developer who produced this. This should never happen! Also, PhantomJS has a bug related to multiple elements with the same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have go into the page context and use the DOM API or jQuery to click this element. CasperJS' `click(selector)` is perfectly capable of handling this with the appropriate selector.

CSS selectors supports matching elements based on their attribute. You use

```
casper.click("button[onclick='activate_access();']");
```

for a perfect match or even

```
casper.click("button[onclick*='activate_access']");
```

for a partial match.